# Problems installing Homebrew on a new OS X installation (SSL error)

Tags: macos, ssl, github, homebrew

Have a fresh OS X installation here (new VM), and when trying to install Homebrew I just get an SSL error.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:-9847
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n --depth=1
```

This is the command I'm using:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Checked around a little bit and tried adding --insecure (or -k) and removing the s from https, but it doesn't seem to help. With --insecure I just get that server aborted the SSL handshake.

Anybody have any idea what is wrong here? "xcode-select --install" has been run as well.

EDIT: Following the suggestion below I dumped the packaged with tcpdump to a pcap file and opened that with tshark. From that I'm getting:

> 1   0.000000 MY_IP_REMOVED -> 192.30.252.130 TCP 78 49451→443 [SYN]
> Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=32 TSval=170479114 TSecr=0
> SACK_PERM=1
>
> 2   0.128228 192.30.252.130 -> MY_IP_REMOVED TCP 78
> 443→49451 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14240 Len=0 MSS=1436 SACK_PERM=1
> TSval=2830778812 TSecr=170479114 WS=1024 [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK
> SEQUENCE INCORRECT]
>
> 3   0.128303 MY_IP_REMOVED -> 192.30.252.130 TCP
> 66 49451→443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=132416 Len=0 TSval=170479237
> TSecr=2830778812
>
> 4   0.150128 MY_IP_REMOVED -> 192.30.252.130 SSL
> 255 Client Hello
>
> 5   0.150913 192.30.252.130 -> MY_IP_REMOVED SSL
> 1158 Continuation Data [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE INCORRECT]
> 6 0.150916 192.30.252.130 -> 81.26.52.196 TCP 64 443→49451 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1101 Ack=190 Win=4237312 Len=0 [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE
> INCORRECT]
>
> 7   0.150961 MY_IP_REMOVED -> 192.30.252.130 TCP 66
> 49451→443 [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=1101 Win=131328 Len=0 TSval=170479257
> TSecr=2830778812
>
> 8   0.150990 MY_IP_REMOVED -> 192.30.252.130 TCP 66
> 49451→443 [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=1102 Win=131328 Len=0 TSval=170479257
> TSecr=2830778812
>
> 9   0.151046 MY_IP_REMOVED -> 192.30.252.130 TCP 66
> 49451→443 [FIN, ACK] Seq=190 Ack=1102 Win=132416 Len=0 TSval=170479257
> TSecr=2830778812
>
> 10   0.151156 192.30.252.130 -> MY_IP_REMOVED TCP 64
> 443→49451 [RST] Seq=1102 Win=4237312 Len=0 [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK
> SEQUENCE INCORRECT]

Comment: Weird. Looks like you're using it right. What OS version? What happens if you just do `git clone 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/'` in a temp directory?

Comment: @AndrewJanke fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:-9847

Comment: Which versions of OS X, `curl`, and `git` are you using?

Comment: @AndrewJanke 10.10.3, 7.37.1 and 2.3.2.  
My local computer has the same versions (but the 10.10.4 beta of OS X), and it has no issues.

Comment: Are you running a `Hackintosh` in a VM then? Does the rest of the networking work properly?

Comment: No this is a VM at a big data center. Not a hackintosh. Everything else seems to work fine.

Comment: What about `curl -v 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/'`? If the command also fails, could you post the output?

Comment: * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.30.252.129...
* Connected to github.com (192.30.252.129) port 443 (#0)
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:-9847
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:-9847

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a clean install of OS X I suspect the problem may be a rare issue (bug?) in `SecureTransport` that could be triggered by a proxy or firewall settings somewhere on your route to github.

Your `libcurl` is compiled against `Security.framework`. The error code `-9847` means [Record overflow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/#//apple_ref/c/econst/errSSLRecordOverflow):

```
A record overflow occurred.
Value
–9847
Description
A record overflow occurred.
Available in OS X v10.3 and later.
```

The error may be pinpointed to this line in [tls1Callouts.c](https://github.com/practicalswift/osx/blob/a9613f74498ff7beef933e50b69ba1057e492822/src/libsecurity_ssl/lib/tls1Callouts.c#L279). It seems that the client receives a record with unexpected length.

It might be related to similar [issue in gnutls](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git/+bug/1397685/comments/5):.

> There are several issues with TLS connections and the F5 firewall, and
>   that looks like the case. That firewall terminates a TLS session if
>   the client hello is between 256 and 512 bytes. If that is the case you
>   can verify using wireshark.
>
> The solution we adopted in later versions
>   of gnutls is to add padding:
>   https://gitlab.com/gnutls/gnutls/commit/b6d29bb1737f96ac44a8ef9cc9fe7f9837e20465

You could try to investigate further with tcpdump/wireshark (replace en0 with your interface name):

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i en0 —n -s 0  -B 524288 -w test.pcap  port 443
```

View your `pcap` file in Wireshark (or capture directly in Wireshark) to get detailed info about each phase. There is a good explanation of `SSL/TLS` on [www.sans.org](http://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/authentication/ssl-tls-hood-34297). For comparison, my (successful) conversation goes like this:

```
$ tshark -r test.pcap
  1   0.000000   10.0.0.125 -> 192.30.252.129 TCP 78 51229→443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=32 TSval=235773429 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1
  2   0.133049 192.30.252.129 -> 10.0.0.125   TCP 74 443→51229 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1851779047 TSecr=235773429 WS=1024
  3   0.133148   10.0.0.125 -> 192.30.252.129 TCP 66 51229→443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131744 Len=0 TSval=235773562 TSecr=1851779047
  4   0.138296   10.0.0.125 -> 192.30.252.129 SSL 255 Client Hello
  5   0.278168 192.30.252.129 -> 10.0.0.125   TLSv1.2 1490 Server Hello
  6   0.278567 192.30.252.129 -> 10.0.0.125   TLSv1.2 1490 Certificate
  7   0.278696   10.0.0.125 -> 192.30.252.129 TCP 66 51229→443 [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=2849 Win=129632 Len=0 TSval=235773707 TSecr=1851779083
  8   0.278910 192.30.252.129 -> 10.0.0.125   TLSv1.2 399 Server Key Exchange
  9   0.278991   10.0.0.125 -> 192.30.252.129 TCP 66 51229→443 [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=3182 Win=130720 Len=0 TSval=235773707 TSecr=1851779083
 10   0.339768   10.0.0.125 -> 192.30.252.129 TLSv1.2 141 Client Key Exchange
 11   0.551009 192.30.252.129 -> 10.0.0.125   TCP 66 443→51229 [ACK] Seq=3182 Ack=265 Win=15360 Len=0 TSval=1851779144 TSecr=235773767
 12   0.551185   10.0.0.125 -> 192.30.252.129 TLSv1.2 157 Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
 13   0.688512 192.30.252.129 -> 10.0.0.125   TCP 66 443→51229 [ACK] Seq=3182 Ack=356 Win=15360 Len=0 TSval=1851779186 TSecr=235773977
 14   0.691643 192.30.252.129 -> 10.0.0.125   TLSv1.2 157 Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
 15   0.691720   10.0.0.125 -> 192.30.252.129 TCP 66 51229→443 [ACK] Seq=356 Ack=3273 Win=130976 Len=0 TSval=235774117 TSecr=1851779186
 16   0.692351   10.0.0.125 -> 192.30.252.129 TLSv1.2 215 Application Data
```

---

If this is really the case a workaround for you might be to compile a custom `libcurl` with `openssl` support and make git use your new `libcurl`. Alternatively you could use `ssh` instead of `https` for connecting to github (if you have your public key registered at github).

Comment: Just did this, but I'm unsure if I'm seeing this specific bug or if it's something else. Added the output to my original question, can you take a look at it @baf?

Comment: Could you post somewhere contents of frames 4 and 5, `Client Hello` and `Continuation Data`. You can get the details adding `-V` option to `tshark` command line.

Comment: With -r -V I get "tshark: "test.pcap" is neither a field nor a protocol name." and with just -V I get "tshark: Invalid capture filter "test.pcap" for interface 'Ethernet'!" @baf

Comment: `tshark -V -r test.pcap`, see [man tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html)

Comment: Here's the entire output after running it through tshark with -V -r: http://pastebin.com/cZg9NWwF @baf

Comment: I don't understand why server doesn't respond with `Server Hello` and what empty SSL section in frame 5 means. I would say corrupted package. Try to ask new question on Server Fault (?), ask why the connection fails and give link to `tshark` output. Maybe someone more experienced will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a workaround to get Homebrew installed, you could try downloading its install script using another tool. E.g. like this:

```
$ python -c "import urllib ; urllib.urlretrieve('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install', 'install.rb')"
$ ruby install.rb
```

Comment: This will not work, as the script will try to invoke `git` again.

Comment: You're right, of course. I didn't notice that it was git itself that had the problem.